# How can I change the node path shown to the user?

Tags: nodes

How can I change the path part of the node URL from `?q=node/2` into something more meaningsful. I want, for instance, to display it like this: `?q=Services`.

Comment: What do you mean by "my favorite node name" and "I want it to display like Services"? Please edit your question.

Comment: Why are you using `?q=` at all? Why don't you simply turn on friendly addresses? It usually works out of the box. Then, go look for pathauto manuals.

Comment: @Mołot, whether clean URLs work out of box or not depends on the Apache config.  Some shared hosting plans don't let users enable `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the [pathauto module](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto)

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.

And you may also want to enable clean url to get rid of the **q=** in the url

To change a particular node, go to **admin/config/search/path/add**
[image]

Or go to the node and scroll down to url path settings and change it there. Make sure to uncheck generate automatic URL alias

[image]

Comment: This worked and I Preciate but how to change the existing ones because it can only change the new ones created after installation  I will be so glad to get an answer

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Drupal 7, to manually set a name for a module, all you need to do is to login as admin and navigate to *Configuration → URL aliases*.  There you can create string aliases for nodes, so that `node/2` is aliased to `Services`.

For the nicest URLs, you should also enable [Clean URLs](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) on you site.

If you do not want to do this yourself, but instead want want names to be assigned to node paths *automatically* (based on some set of rules), then you can install and enable the [PathAuto module](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto).